# FullCalendar and json events

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, fullcalendar

I try to make availability calendar with FullCalendar.js. Everything works fine if I call events from database in my index.php, but when I try to get events via json I get nothing. Calendar is showing but normally, but not showing events. When I look in smjestaj-rezervacija-kalendar.php I get:

```
[ { title: 'Rezervirano', start: '2015-01-30', allDay: true } , { title: 'Rezervirano', start: '2015-01-31', allDay: true } , { title: 'Rezervirano', start: '2015-02-01', allDay: true } ]
```

so it works. Anyone having idea why it doesn't show on calendar, what am I doing wrong?

index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        // Event calendar js
        try{
            $('#utopia-fullcalendar-2').fullCalendar({
                header:{
                    left:'prev,next',
                    center:'title',
                    right:''
                },
                dayNames: ['Nedjelja','Ponedjeljak','Utorak','Srijeda','Četvrtak','Petak','Subota'],
                dayNamesShort: ['Ned','Pon','Uto','Sri','Čet','Pet','Sub'],
                monthNames: ['Siječanj','Veljača','Ožujak','Travanj','Svibanj','Lipanj','Srpanj','Kolovoz','Rujan','Listopad','Studeni','Prosinac'],
                monthNamesShort: ['Sij','Velj','Ožu','Tra','Svi','Lip','Srp','Kol','Ruj','Lis','Stu','Pro'],
                firstDay:1,
                editable:false,
                height:540,
                events: 'smjestaj-rezervacija-kalendar.php?SmjestajID=<?=$_GET['SmjestajID'];?>'
            });
        } catch (e){
            errorMessage(e);
        }
    });
    </script>
```

and here is my smjestaj-rezervacija-kalendar.php:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/json; charset=utf-8');
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/admin/config.php");
echo '[';
$SmjestajID = $_GET['SmjestajID'];
$rezultat_kalendar = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM smjestaj_kalendar WHERE KalendarSmjestaj=$SmjestajID ORDER BY KalendarID ASC");
$broj_unosa = mysqli_num_rows($rezultat_kalendar);
$i = 1;
while ($redak_kalendar = mysqli_fetch_array($rezultat_kalendar))
    {   ?> {
                    title: 'Rezervirano',
                    start: '<?=$redak_kalendar['KalendarDatum']?>',
                    allDay: true
                } 
<?php
        if ($i <> $broj_unosa){
            echo ',';
        }
        $i ++;
    }
echo ']';
?>
```

I try with http://fajitanachos.com/Fullcalendar-and-recurring-events/ json file, but still get nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I googled and find that in json should be no html object, so I remove *header('Content-type: text/json; charset=utf-8');* and go with array instead of html. This answer was helpfull: [How do I get FullCalendar to display information from my JSON feed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081546/how-do-i-get-fullcalendar-to-display-information-from-my-json-feed)

```
<?php
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/admin/config.php");

$SmjestajID = $_GET['SmjestajID'];
$rezultat_kalendar = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM smjestaj_kalendar WHERE KalendarSmjestaj=$SmjestajID ORDER BY KalendarID ASC");
while ($record = mysqli_fetch_array($rezultat_kalendar)) {
    $event_array[] = array(
        'id' => $record['KalendarID'],
        'title' => "Rezervirano",
        'start' => $record['KalendarDatum'],
        'allDay' => true
     );
}
echo json_encode($event_array);
?>
```

Comment: your header should be `header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');` when returning pure JSON data; charset is optional.